# Select first file by default in netrw

Tags: neovim, netrw

When I open a directory in netrw, the `..` directory at the top is selected by default

[image]

How can I make netrw always select the first listing that is not `..` or `.` by default instead?

---

Thanks to a comment, I tried changing the sort order to put `..` and `.` at the bottom of the list. So I've tried setting

```
:let g:netrw_sort_sequence='[\/]$,,\.bak$,\.o$,\.h$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.obj$,^\(?!\.|\.\.\)$'
```

But my netrw looks exactly the same after doing this.

I thought the extra pattern `^\(?!\.|\.\.\)$` would match any name that is NOT `.` or `..` exactly, and then sort those before sorting `..` and `.`.

Comment: Some lateral thinking: a different sort, or hiding hidden files?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble oh thanks! Good idea, so I just checked and found `g:netrw_sort_sequence`, and I tried setting it to the default one with an extra `^\(?!\.|\.\.\)$`, but it didn't do what I thought it would

Comment: It’s worth [edit]ing in rather than leaving in the comments